# Flexbox Form for Mobile not responding

Tags: css, forms, flexbox

I would like to have the #ClickWordList li items to go under the message box. I've tried just about everything and the layout isn't budging. I've looked online and have found 0 solutions. Any suggestions highly welcomed.

Html :

```
<h3 class="title">What new feature or section would you add?</h3>
<h3 class="message-box">Message Box</h3>

<div id="message-box-container">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="message">
            <label for="txtMessage"></label>
            <textarea id="txtMessage" name="txtMessage" class="txtDropTarget ui-droppable"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="clickable-questions">
            <ul id="ClickWordList">
                <li id="click1"></li>
                <li id="click2"></li>
                <li id="click3"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--message-box-container-->
```

CSS:

```
/*********** free form message styles ******/

.form{
    display: flex;
}
.message {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 1;
}

.message > textarea {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 18rem;
    max-height: 12rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
}

.clickable-questions {
    flex: 1;
    order: 2;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

#ClickWordList > li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies where you placed `flex-direction`

You put it inside `.message` the way the mark-up is read makes `.message` end at the next `</div>` tag.

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="message"><--!this is start of message container!-->
      <label for="txtMessage"></label>
      <textarea id="txtMessage" name="txtMessage" class="txtDropTarget ui-droppable"></textarea>
    </div><--!this is end of message container!-->
```

You use css to set `flex-direction` to `.message` , but as you can see nothing is nested inside `.message` except `<label>` and `<textarea>` .

You can fix your problem simply by moving `flex-direction:;` and `flex-wrap:;` to the `.form` container to get your results.

```
.form{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Be sure to verify how your containers are nested. This will save you time when you troubleshoot a issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/xzq8mvju/